# $.getJSON call not working

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am beginner to code and right now working on a challenge in FCC.
The problem is I am unable to run a $.getJSON call in codepen.
I have read previous question on Stack Overflow but still was not able to comprehend. So please somebody shed a light to clear my code-learning roadblock.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var url = "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/freecodecamp?callback=?";
 $.getJSON(url,function(data1){
   if(data1.stream===null){
     $("#fccStatus").html("FCC is currently OFFLINE");
   }
   else{
     $("#fccStatus").html("FCC is ONLINE");
   }
 });
});
```

I am even not able to run this code in codepen

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $.getJSON('data.json',function(result){
    alert("success");
  });
});
```

I am using Google Chrome, but also have tried this in Firefox

The HTML code is as follows:

```
 <div class="container">
      <div id="header" class="text-center">
  <h1>TwitchTV JSON API</h1>
  <h2>Free Code Camp</h2>
  <h3 id="fccStatus"></h3>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <h1>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      Logo:
      </div>
     <div class="col-md-4">
      Display Name:
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
      Status:
      </div>
    </h1>
  </div>
  <div id="followerInfo">

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you see any errors in the console? Check F12 and see the console?

Comment: You did include jQuery.. Did you?

Comment: yeah i included jQuery. In the console its saying a reference error that jQUery is not defined

Comment: Can you please copy your html? Thanks. The code works for me ------------------------------$(document).ready(function(){
  $.getJSON('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1',function(result){
    console.log("success");
  });
});-----------------------------------

changed a few lines to have an actual response from a rest api

Comment: Ok, so you didn't include it... At least not before using it.

Comment: I think he might have included it but he is running his script before the actual inclusion of the file.

Comment: @baao- i included jQuery befor writing my code.

Comment: @mnemosdev here is the code: <div class="container">
  <div id="header" class="text-center">
  <h1>TwitchTV JSON API</h1>
  <h2>Free Code Camp</h2>
  <h3 id="fccStatus"></h3>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <h1>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      Logo:
      </div>
     <div class="col-md-4">
      Display Name:
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
      Status:
      </div>
    </h1>
  </div>
  <div id="followerInfo">
  
  </div>
</div>

Comment: @RajatChauhan please upload all the html code inside your question, not in the comments, and give proper formatting. That will be helpful for us and will avoid bad voting for you.

Comment: Also, the code you wrote doesn't include any mentions to javascript or jquery at all!

Comment: @mnemosdev i am not even getting the json call you mentioned in your comment.

Comment: Because you haven't setup jquery. Include your HTML in the question and I will tell you what to do.

Comment: @mnemosdev i am using codepen. And i've included jQuery in settings

Comment: post a link to your codepen pen, then

Comment: http://codepen.io/rajat1307/pen/mRbQqK

Comment: check answer below, just edited, thanks :)

Comment: Also, mate, this is not a valid cb function: https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/freecodecamp?callback=?

Check for an endpoint that works otherwise it will always fail to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: You included jquery-ui and NOT jquery in your codepen, hence it doesn't work because of that! Twitch changed its API and you need to register a clientID if you want to make any requests to their API. You can go to this [webpage](https://dev.twitch.tv/docs/v5/guides/using-the-twitch-api/) and follow the instructions there. What is happening to your requests right now is a 400 error each time you make a request. Quoting the API documentation:
To identify your application to the API, every request must include your application’s client ID, either explicitly or implicitly by including an OAuth token. If you use an OAuth token in your request, the API figures out the client ID for you.

> Requests without a client ID fail with an HTTP 400 error.
>
> To get a client ID, register a developer application on the
>   connections page of your Twitch account. Once you have your client ID,
>   you can send it via:
>
> Request header (Client-ID: XXXXX) Query-string parameter
>   (https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/users/44322889?client_id=XXXXX)

Old post, for sake of full disclosure:

You should upload your HTML to make sure that you actually included the files correctly.

I tried this code, which is like yours, in codepen and everything works fine

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $.getJSON('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1',function(result){
    console.log("success");
  });
});
```

I think you might have a problem with a CDN where jquery is at, but before that, given that you have a reference error and jQuery is not defined. You can look at this pen I wrote for you:
[Codepen example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qRWLEY)

If you upload your HTML, like you did in the comments under your post, you will notice that this:

```
 <div class="container">
      <div id="header" class="text-center">
  <h1>TwitchTV JSON API</h1>
  <h2>Free Code Camp</h2>
  <h3 id="fccStatus"></h3>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <h1>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      Logo:
      </div>
     <div class="col-md-4">
      Display Name:
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
      Status:
      </div>
    </h1>
  </div>
  <div id="followerInfo">

  </div>
</div>
```

Is not friendly formatted, which is fine for now, but also doesn't include any mentions to any javascript or jquery files. Where are the DOCTYPE, html, body, head tags?
You are missing all the script tags that connect your script and enable jQuery to run.

```
<html>
<head></head>
 <body>
 <div class="container">
      <div id="header" class="text-center">
  <h1>TwitchTV JSON API</h1>
  <h2>Free Code Camp</h2>
  <h3 id="fccStatus"></h3>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <h1>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      Logo:
      </div>
     <div class="col-md-4">
      Display Name:
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
      Status:
      </div>
    </h1>
  </div>
  <div id="followerInfo">

  </div>
</div>
<script src="/path/to/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="/path/to/your-script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Also, since you are doing the FCC API Challenge, you might want to refer to this tutorial post, just if you get stuck tho, otherwise it doesn't make sense. [FCC Twitch API](https://medium.freecodecamp.com/building-a-twitchtv-app-project-8824d61fe7a5#.3cbi3st7r)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Have you checked my pen? http://codepen.io/rajat1307/pen/mRbQqK

Comment: Yes, the jquery is not the only problem, you are making a callback that is wrong, infact if you go to the address https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/freecodecamp?callback=? you will get an error

Comment: Thanks a lot..Really appreciate your help

Comment: Check my changed pen so you can read the error yourself:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qRWLEY?editors=1012

Error appears in codepen console